# topbar with interchange in Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I´m trying to load a topbar on a breakpoint with an interchange. Somebody know how can I control when the template is loaded to call the topbar init? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use presentational classes? You will have to reinit the topbar after loading foundation / dom ready for it to work as you intend it. Check out how they do it on the foundation docs site. It is just a hide-for-small on the topbar nav. in that specific case, they then use the offcanvas for small, by using hide-for-medium-up.

Comment: I saw it but I don't want to have unnecesary html in the basic and mobile htlm. Finally I'm calling to the topbar init method when the content change to desktop version.

Comment: I control this with the intechange component, changing an 1x1px png with the names small.png, medium.png and large.png and the event replace. When the image is large.png I load the top bar via ajax and call the init method in the success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I control this with the intechange component, changing an 1x1px png with the names small.png, medium.png and large.png and the event replace. When the image is large.png I load the top bar via ajax and call the init method in the success function.

In the html:

```
<img data-interchange="[img/small.png, (default)], [img/small.png, (small)], [img/medium.png, (medium)], [img/large.png, (large)]" alt="" role="presentation" id="size-ckecher"/>
```

In the JS:

```
$(document).on('replace', '#size-ckecher', function (e, new_path, original_path) {


    if(new_path.indexOf("small")!=-1){


    }else if(new_path.indexOf("medium")!=-1){



    }else if(new_path.indexOf("large")!=-1){

        $(document).foundation();   
    }
})
```

Comment: I think a better solution would be to use modernizr, check the size of the screen and then ajax load the top-bar. I don't think you are gaining anything with interchange and having an additional http request(s) to the server for the same functionality. Not to mention the increased file size from the interchange plugin, unless you are using it heavily elsewhere on the site. I understand your logic, only serving up content for that specific device device, but I would consider general front end best practices and test your solution in faster in real word situations to see if it *is* faster.